# Where to get a shared hosting with MySQL 5.5 or higher?

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I need to utilize the features of 5.5 and my current host (liquid web) doesn't provide 5.5 for their shared plans. I do not want to get a dedicated server right now, but will in the future. I just need shared hosting at the moment that supports 5.5

Comment: Consider renting a VPS; they're cheap, but still allow you to install anything you want on them.

Comment: Take a look at 'How do I meet hosting that meets my requirements' http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements

Comment: Voting to close as dupe, but also how much work are you willing to put into this? Shared hosts tend to be a bit conservative, so it's probably going to be a while before you find this already set up for you. But the question is also not necessarily just about shared vs dedicated/VPS. For example, if the reason you don't want a dedicated server is a matter of cost, there are some shared hosts that give you enough system access that you could do a custom MySQL install.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon offers a 1 year free micro instance, you could setup your own server with MySQL 5.5